# I am trying to write my first bit of JavaScript for my google sheet

Tags: javascript, function, google-sheets

this is my first ever bit of JavaScript I have tried to use (I have done a fair bit of python before this).
I just wrote these two functions for a Google Sheets.
When I try and run the function, it gives me the error of "Result was not a number".
I have no clue as of where I went wrong because, as I said, I am very new to Javascript and this all just looks alien to me!

```
 function myDays(date1 , date2 , followers1 , followers2) {
      const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
      const firstDate = new Date(2008, 1, 12);
      const secondDate = new Date(2008, 1, 22);
      const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
    }


function LinearGradient(date1 , date2 , followers1 , followers2) {
  days =myDays(date2,date1);
  followers = followers2 - followers1;
  gradient = followers / days;
  return gradient;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never `return` a value from `myDays`. So `days = myDays(date2,date1);` will result in `days` being `undefined`.

When we look further `gradient = followers / days;` will result in `gradient` always being `NaN` (not a number). Since something divided by `undefined` will always yield `NaN`.

To solve the issue add a `return` statement.

```
function myDays(date1 , date2 , followers1 , followers2) {
  const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
  const firstDate = new Date(2008, 1, 12);
  const secondDate = new Date(2008, 1, 22);
  const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
  return diffDays; // <- return the difference in days
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue lies in your date declaration.- By default, `new Date()` will output an object.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

See the example below:

```js
//this is an object
const firstDate = new Date(2008, 1, 12);
console.log(typeof firstDate);

//this is a number
const numberFirstDate = Date.now(2008, 1, 12);
console.log(typeof numberFirstDate);
```

Comment: You can still subtract two date objects from each other. The [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) method will be called and the returned timestamp is used. `new Date() - new Date() //=> 0`